# How to set image on EAGL VIEW

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, opengl-es

I want to put images from my photo library in to the EAGL view for some further processing. The image that are already in our resources folder will be taken by itself but mltiple or images from photo library can't. So any one knows how to put image on EAGL view in open GLES.

Regtards viral

Comment: Ok any one know how to add multiple image to texture in open GLES, as the images will be loaded from  loadTexture("Image.png", &Input, &renderer); this function.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the Apple sample called [GLImageProcessing](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html): it demonstrate how to use load an UIImage and put it in an EAGL view.

Comment: I've viewed it, but it allows me to get only a single image not images from the library. I m not able to get multiple images so any other way??

Comment: Perhaps you could extrapolate from a single image to multiple images from the library??

Comment: You can load the various images as textures and then map them on different OpenGL quads (one for each image).

As for the multiple selection, I don't know if the image picker allows it (never tried).